# Why did my CSS for replacing a list item bullet with a background icon stop working?

Tags: css, background-image, bulletedlist

This CSS used to work with social media icons replacing list item bullets, but now it is giving me a list showing the bullets, the icons, and the text smashed together.

Why has "list-style: none;" stopped working?

```css
.social-follow {
  margin: 0.2em 0 2em 3em;
}

.social-follow ul.follow-background {
  list-style: none outside !important;
  margin: 0 0 0 0.6em;
  padding: 0 0 0 0.6em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.social-follow ul.follow-background + li.follow {
  line-height: 32;
  background: no-repeat left 1px;
  /** fixed vertical position **/
  margin: 0.3em 0 0 -0.6em;
  padding: 0 0 0 2.7em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li.follow.chapicon {
  background: url('https://wdcb.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/chapter_logo_54pxtype-32x32-28x28.png') no-repeat left 1px;
}

li.follow.facebookicon {
  background: url('https://wdcb.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/facebook-icon-28x28.png') no-repeat left 1px;
}

li.follow.flickricon {
  background: url('https://wdcb.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/fluid-flickr-logo-28x28.png') no-repeat left 1px;
}

li.follow.instaicon {
  background: url('https://wdcb.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/instagram-logo-28x28.png') no-repeat left 1px;
}

li.follow.linkedinicon {
  background: url('https://wdcb.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/linkedin-logo-28x28.png') no-repeat left 1px;
}

li.follow.pinteresticon {
  background: url('https://wdcb.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/pinterest-logo-28x28.png') no-repeat left 1px;
}

li.follow.rssblueicon {
  background: url('https://wdcb.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/rss-logo-blue-28x28.png') no-repeat left 1px;
}

li.follow.skylineicon {
  background: url('https://wdcb.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/logo-skyline_only-28x28.png') no-repeat left 1px;
}

li.follow.twittericon {
  background: url('https://wdcb.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/twitter-logo-28x28.png') no-repeat left 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-follow">
  <ul class="follow-background">
    <li class="follow facebookicon"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/STCWDCMB/" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Facebook page</a></li>
    <li class="follow flickricon"><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/stcwdc/sets" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Flickr Photo Albums</a></li>
    <li class="follow instaicon"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/stc_wdcb/" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Instagram</a></li>
    <li class="follow linkedinicon"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=156478" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">LinkedIn Group</a></li>
    <li class="follow pinteresticon"><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/stcwdcmb/" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Pinterest page</a></li>
    <li class="follow twittericon"><a href="https://twitter.com/stcwdc" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Twitter @stcwdc</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Current result in Opera, Firefox, Safari, and Google Chrome:
[image]

Comment: spelling mistake !mportant;

Comment: `.social-follow ul.follow-background+li.follow`must be `.social-follow ul.follow-background li.follow`

Comment: @Madhuri Yes, thanks. I thought I had fixed that before I posted this question.

Comment: @connexo who says `line-height: 32'` won't work. Please if you don't know CSS, don't say what you don't know. CSS works fine most of the time without units, in fact, line-height is used that way !

Comment: What you could have said is that using it that way violated the specifications. But using it like that works. `padding: 0` works also !

Comment: @connexo There is a good article called "Understanding use of the +, >, and ~ symbols in CSS selectors" at https://levelup.gitconnected.com/understanding-use-of-the-and-symbols-in-css-selectors-95552eb436f5

Comment: @connexo I am using unitless line-height as recommended by Matt Smith at `https://allthingssmitty.com/2017/01/30/nope-nope-nope-line-height-is-unitless/` , Eric Meyer `https://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2006/02/08/unitless-line-heights/` , and as explained in the article "How CSS line-height works and best practices" at `https://dev.to/lampewebdev/css-line-height-jjp` under "Default value and unitless value".

Comment: `.social-follow ul.follow-background+li.follow` can never match anything. `li` cannot be a sibling of `ul`.

Comment: @connexo I should have used the general sibling combinator (~) tilda that matches all iterations of the second element, that are following the first element and are children of the same parent element. Specifications are at Selectors Level 4 (Selectors 4) [link](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators). Without the tilda or the +, the list items is not rendered correctly and are all spaced out instead of together. <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxq4xpiqn3g5o7u/very-spread-out-list-items.png?dl=0" width="98" height="300" alt="very spread out list items">.

Comment: Why did this question get a negative vote? The question is still not answered. The CSS used to work before the latest release of WordPress version 5.8.2. But somehow link-style: none is no longer working--the bullets are still showing. Why?

Comment: Doesn't matter if you use `+` or `~` in your selector `.social-follow ul.follow-background+li.follow` - either can never match anything as **`li` cannot be a sibling of `ul`**. *Without the tilda or the +, the list items is not rendered correctly* the obvious reason being that **with  `+` or `~` the rules never get applied**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here, but first just to note that one problem has gone away. The image in the question shows bullet symbols as well as the icons but the code as currently presented in the question does not show the bullet points. I believe this was dealt with in comments (a typo on !important).

Now there are a couple of remaining things. It is not OK to have unitless settings for line-height other than 0 (which can be unitless for most things) so this snippet applies a px which it assumes is what is wanted. [Note in the snippet in the question this would not be picked up as the class it was in was never executed, see next point. I believe some browsers may be 'kind' and assume px, but don't rely on it].

As @connexo has pointed out, there is one chunk of CSS which is never applied:

```
.social-follow ul.follow-background + li.follow {
  line-height: 32;
  background: no-repeat left 1px;
  /** fixed vertical position **/
  margin: 0.3em 0 0 -0.6em;
  padding: 0 0 0 2.7em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator):

> The adjacent sibling combinator (+) separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it immediately follows the first element, and both are children of the same parent element.

The li elements are children of the ul element, not siblings, so this selector is ignored.

However, in curing that problem we've uncovered another one - there is a background setting which has more specificity than another. So this one:

```
background: no-repeat left 1px;
```

now overwrites this one:

```
  background: url('https://wdcb.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/chapter_logo_54pxtype-32x32-28x28.png') no-repeat left 1px;
```

Remember that background is a composite property - setting several things.

For clarity this snippet separates things out into the individual components.

```css
.social-follow {
  margin: 0.2em 0 2em 3em;
}

.social-follow ul.follow-background {
  list-style: none outside !important;
  margin: 0 0 0 0.6em;
  padding: 0 0 0 0.6em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.social-follow ul.follow-background li.follow {
  line-height: 32px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left 1px;
  /** fixed vertical position **/
  margin: 0.3em 0 0 -0.6em;
  padding: 0 0 0 2.7em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li.follow.chapicon {
  background-image: url('https://wdcb.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/chapter_logo_54pxtype-32x32-28x28.png');
}

li.follow.facebookicon {
  background-image: url('https://wdcb.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/facebook-icon-28x28.png');
}

li.follow.flickricon {
  background-image: url('https://wdcb.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/fluid-flickr-logo-28x28.png');
}

li.follow.instaicon {
  background-image: url('https://wdcb.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/instagram-logo-28x28.png');
}

li.follow.linkedinicon {
  background-image: url('https://wdcb.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/linkedin-logo-28x28.png');
}

li.follow.pinteresticon {
  background-image: url('https://wdcb.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/pinterest-logo-28x28.png');
}

li.follow.rssblueicon {
  background-image: url('https://wdcb.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/rss-logo-blue-28x28.png');
}

li.follow.skylineicon {
  background-image: url('https://wdcb.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/logo-skyline_only-28x28.png');
}

li.follow.twittericon {
  background-image: url('https://wdcb.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/twitter-logo-28x28.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="social-follow">
  <ul class="follow-background">
    <li class="follow facebookicon"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/STCWDCMB/" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Facebook page</a></li>
    <li class="follow flickricon"><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/stcwdc/sets" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Flickr Photo Albums</a></li>
    <li class="follow instaicon"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/stc_wdcb/" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Instagram</a></li>
    <li class="follow linkedinicon"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=156478" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">LinkedIn Group</a></li>
    <li class="follow pinteresticon"><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/stcwdcmb/" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Pinterest page</a></li>
    <li class="follow twittericon"><a href="https://twitter.com/stcwdc" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Twitter @stcwdc</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is the URL of the page it is in. <https://wdcb.stcwdc.org/social-media/>

Comment: Hi, sorry I don't see a problem with that page, are you still having a problem? Did any of the answer solve your problems?

Comment: The new code suggestions above worked after I made changes to it to match my current class names. I had been trying so many variations and redoing everything from scratch that the class names used in the snippet no longer worked. It is now displaying correctly except for when I try to add WAI Aria to the code for screen readers using aria-labelling then all the icons disappear. That's a different problem I am looking into. Thanks for your help